# Is there a way to allow an object function to return a variable without passing in that variable in the constructor?

Tags: oracle, user-defined-types

I'm working on a project that requires me to create many different subtypes under one supertype. This supertype is supposed to have a function that gets a name, but the name will only come from the subtype. Is there a way to create the type and allow it to have a function that returns a value from a subtype?

I have tried just removing the function altogether, but in order to complete this project, I need it to have this function, because the function is used through this type to get the information from the objects that I insert into a table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
  TYPE test_obj IS OBJECT
  ( OBJ_ID NUMBER
  , OBJ_NAME VARCHAR2(30)
  , CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION test_obj
  ( OBJ_ID   NUMBER
  , OBJ_NAME VARCHAR2)
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT
  , MEMBER FUNCTION GET_OBJ_NAME RETURN VARCHAR2
  , MEMBER PROCEDURE SET_OBJ_NAME
  ( ONAME VARCHAR2)
  , MEMBER FUNCTION GET_NAME RETURN VARCHAR2
  , MEMBER FUNCTION TO_STRING RETURN VARCHAR2)
  INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL;
  /

CREATE OR REPLACE
   TYPE BODY test_obj IS   
   CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION test_obj
   ( OBJ_ID NUMBER
   , OBJ_NAME VARCHAR2 )
   RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
   BEGIN
      self.OBJ_ID := OBJ_ID;
      self.OBJ_NAME := OBJ_NAME;
      RETURN;
   END test_obj;

   MEMBER FUNCTION GET_OBJ_NAME
   RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN OBJ_NAME;
   END GET_OBJ_NAME;

   MEMBER PROCEDURE SET_OBJ_NAME
   (OBJ_NAME VARCHAR2) IS
   BEGIN
      self.OBJ_NAME := OBJ_NAME;
   END SET_OBJ_NAME;

-- This is the function that I need to fix
   MEMBER FUNCTION GET_NAME
   RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   NAME VARCHAR2(30)
   BEGIN
      RETURN NAME;
   END GET_NAME;

   MEMBER FUNCTION TO_STRING
   RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN '['||self.OBJ_ID||']['||self.OBJ_NAME||']';
   END TO_STRING;
END;
/
```

I want to be able to override the `GET_NAME` function in subclasses, but I don't want to pass in a NAME variable, because this type won't ever receive a NAME variable, the subtypes are the only ones that will receive it. I won't be able to instantiate it properly if I have the name passed in through the constructor.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your posted code doesn't compile. You have different parameter names for SET_OBJ_NAME() in the spec and the body. Also, you're missing a semicolon in the declaration section of GET_NAME() - `NAME VARCHAR2(30);`. Is that what you're trying to fix? If not, please clarify your question to explain what you're trying to achieve. Maybe posting code for a subtype would make it easier to understand the behaviour you're trying to implement.

Comment: Also, are you sure you need to instantiate the supertype?